# io.file.Readalllines works for one file name but not for anyothers also does not throw exception on invalid filename

Tags: vb.net, winforms, file.readalllines

The files I am trying to read are in a file called systemstate in the  bin\debug file. I have a text file call systemdetails in that file and a file in there called Products and a file of products called P0 containing the rest of the text files

in the following lines of code the first readalllines works, the rest fails without any exception raised and the program continues to run as if nothing happened.

**in the form1.vb file**

```
    Public Sub init()
    If start Then
        productcount = Int(IO.File.ReadAllLines(filestoreloc + systemfile)(0).Split()(1))
        For i As Integer = 0 To productcount
            Dim id As String = Str(i)

            Dim det As String() = IO.File.ReadAllLines(filestoreloc + Product.location + "P" + id + Product.detailsfile)
            Dim desc As String() = IO.File.ReadAllLines(filestoreloc + Product.location + "P" + id + Product.descriptionfile)
            Dim rev As String() = IO.File.ReadAllLines(filestoreloc + Product.location + "P" + id + Product.reviewfile)

            products.Add(New Product(det, desc, extractRecords(rev, Product.revstartmark, Product.revendmark)))
        Next
        start = False
    End If
End Sub
```

***This method is invoked from the Form1_load method***

these are the variables used in the above code:

**in the form1.vb file**

```
Property filestoreloc As String = "systemstate\"

Property systemfile As String = "systemdetails.txt"

Property productcount As Integer

Property start As Boolean = True
```

**in the product.vb file**

```
Public Shared Property location As String = "Products\"
Public Shared Property detailsfile As String = "\details.txt"
Public Shared Property descriptionfile As String = "\description.txt"
Public Shared Property reviewfile As String = "\reviews.txt"

Public Shared Property revstartmark As String = "[REVIEWSTART]"
Public Shared Property revendmark As String = "[REVIEWEND]"
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the rest fail"?  If they aren't throwing exceptions, what do they do?  Return a null or empty array?  Skip out of the method without continuing?

Comment: @StevenDoggart when I get to the 1st failing readalllines in debug mode and I step over it the system stops debugging and the program is shown to be running

Comment: the product.add part which comes after all the reads does not even run

Comment: So it is probably throwing an exception, it's just catching it and eating it somewhere else.  Try putting a Try/Catch block right around that one line of code and see if you can catch the exception and see what it is.

Comment: @StevenDoggart it says directory not found also I have now noticed when I convert 0 to a string it becomes space and then 0: " 0"

Comment: I Trimmed the string and now no exception is thrown. they all work thank you! also should I close the question now?

Comment: You could answer it yourself, or delete it, or leave it open.  It's up to you :)

Comment: @StevenDoggart wait how do I get my program to throw exceptions properly

Comment: Exceptions thrown in Form Load are usually not caught due to a well known bug.  Move your code to Form Shown or a button click

Comment: @StevenDoggart okay thanks

Answer (score 1):

an exception was not showing up. this exception was because the directory couldn't be found because when I converted the id to a string there was a leading space @StevenDoggart helped me detect the exception